# How to implement sidebar with settings for each component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am just getting started with vuejs and after following a course on udemy I feel ready to dig in. To get started I need some pointers.

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

I have created a component call it example, when I click on the component I need on the left side of the component to show the settings for just that component. If I change those settings they should only be changed for selected component. If I select the second component settings with its own values should then be displayed to the left.

What is best way to do this? Sidebar on the left should only be visible if the component is clicked/selected. So I am guessing that the sidebar component which we can call settings should be a child of example component so that I can comunicate with this when it should be visible or not.

My question is how do I position the child component to the left like I have "mocked up" on the screenshot. Is it possible to copy settings component html into the left sidebar each time I click an example component?

How would you implement something like this?